# How can I determine the amounts of potassium bicarbonate and potassium sulfate in a solution?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I have an aquaeous solution of potassium bicarbonate and potassium sulfate. I want to find out the proportions of both compounds in the solution. What would be an efficient procedure?

Note that I do not have an analytical balance or other fancy equipment. I can do simple procedures like titrations.

One idea I had is that I could titrate it with an acid of known molarity. That would react with the potassium bicarbonate and when the pH became neutral as shown by an indicator, that would tell me how much KHC03 I had.

The sulfate is a more tricky problem.

Comment: Hint: how could you easily remove the bicarbonate ions? Measure what comes out. Then get the dry weight of what remains and you can calculate proportions.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't have an analytical balance.

Comment: There must be some sulfates that are insoluble in water, hmm...